# Powershell ImportExcel module adding worksheets issue

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to write data to an Excel workbook in three different worksheets, but only the first data written appears in the specified worksheet with the other worksheets created but are empty.
Here's the code:

```
$outputFile = 'output.xlsx'
$excel = $null
$InputFiles = 'file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt'

# get a list of FileInfo objects
$files = $InputFiles | ForEach-Object { Get-Item $_ }

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $content = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path $file

    $mappings = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Mapping]

    foreach ($line in $content)
    {
      // read the mappings here to a Mapping PS class instance
      // and add to the list of mappings
    }

    $worksheetName = $file.BaseName

    if ($excel -eq $null)
    {
        # ensure file doesn't exist
        if (Test-Path -Path $OutputFile) { Remove-Item -Path $OutputFile -ErrorAction Stop}

        $excel = $mappings | Export-Excel -WorksheetName $worksheetName -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow -TableStyle None -Path $OutputFile -PassThru
        $ws = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets[$worksheetName]
    }
    else
    {
        $ws = Add-Worksheet -ExcelPackage $excel -WorksheetName $worksheetName -MoveToStart
        $null = $mappings | Export-Excel -WorksheetName $ws -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize -BoldTopRow -TableStyle None -PassThru
    }

    Set-Format -Worksheet $ws -Range "B2:B$($mappings.Count)" -WrapText
    Set-Format -Worksheet $ws -Range 'A:C' -VerticalAlignment Top
}

if ($excel -ne $null)
{
    Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $excel -Show
}
```

I'd expect that from having saved the ExcelPackage reference in $excel after the first call to Export-Excel (creating the worksheet) I could re-use it in the next iteration of the loop to create the remaining worksheets and populate their data, but all that happens is that the worksheets get created but they're blank.

Is there a bug in that subsequent calls to Export-Excel don't work when not specifying a path?

Comment: Would it help if I show you how to create a multi worksheet excel file leaving aside the details of your current code (such as `Set-Format` and other stuff) ?

Comment: Considering that the workbook has blank sheets it doesn't sound like a path issue. More that it is not able to use whatever data is in `$mappings` as source data. Are you able to export any given set of `$mappings` to its own workbook with the data populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is leaving aside the abstraction in your code and giving you a simple example of how you can create a multi worksheet Excel file with the [ImportExcel Module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel):

```
$wsheet1 = Get-Process | Select-Object ProcessName, Id
$wsheet2 = Get-Service | Select-Object Name, Status
$wsheet3 = Get-ChildItem $pwd | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime

# Create a new Package
$pkg = Open-ExcelPackage -Path path\to\theExport.xlsx -Create
# Export to each Worksheet
$pkg = $wsheet1 | Export-Excel -ExcelPackage $pkg -WorksheetName Process -PassThru
$pkg = $wsheet2 | Export-Excel -ExcelPackage $pkg -WorksheetName Services -PassThru
$pkg = $wsheet3 | Export-Excel -ExcelPackage $pkg -WorksheetName myFiles -PassThru
Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $pkg
```